# Adding a button to Outlook 2007 to add a text from HTML file

Tags: button, outlook, customization, add-in, signature

I'm looking for help to add a Button on the Outlook 2007 Message Ribbon to, when its clicked, add the text in a HTML file.

My first questions is:
   Is this possible?

   What are the possible language you can do this is?
   What languague is the the best for this?

EDIT: 
I now know how to create the button and so on. But what I need help with now is the coding.
What's the code for when clicking the button it will add the HTML file (the main signature) to the bottom of the mail?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about all languages support, but C#.NET has a lot of support because both product are from same vendors.

You can use visual studio IDE 2010 which already has templates of outlook add-in for MS-Office with ribbon support also.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194126/Creating-an-Outlook-2010-Add-In

Comment: Thanks for your respone! But this is for 2010, is it any big difference between the two version on making add-ins?

This guide doesn't really explain on making a button on the Ribbon in a existing "tab"

Comment: Hello, With some more googleing and reading i understood some more, this link was helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608593.aspx But now i need help with the code to say, put this html file in the end of the mail. Not as an attachment but as "HTMLText". Any idea?